# About SQL SERVER LEFT JOIN and Group by

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables,Blog table has a FK BlogTagID column point to BlogTag table:

Blog table:

```
BlogID BlogTagID BlogTitle
  1       2        test1
  2       1        test2
  3       2        test3
```

BlogTag table:

```
BlogTagID BlogTagName
  1        JAVA        
  2        .NET        
  3        PHP
```

I would like to get the result:

```
BlogTagName  count
   JAVA         1
   .NET         2
   PHP          0
```

How to get this?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
select BlogTagName, count(blogid)
from BlogTag bt
left join Blog b on b.blogtagid = bt.BlogTagID
group by BlogTagName
```

SQL FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/356c5/8/0

Comment: Its because .net is in two blog.. so it will become two diff row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/356c5/15/0

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
SELECT BlogTagName,COUNT(BlogTagID) FROM Blog b JOIN BlogTagID bt WHERE b.BlogTagID=bt.BlogTagID GROUP BY BlogTagID;
```